# Holding points are absorbing

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_{t},\mathbb{P}^{x})$ be a homogeneous Markov process. It is well known that for some $\lambda=\lambda(x)\in[0,\infty]$ and all $t>0$, $$\mathbb{P}^{x}(\tau_{x}>t)=\exp(-\lambda t),$$  where $\tau_{x}=\inf\{t>0,\ X_{t}\neq x\}$ is the escape time. I want to show that **if $X$ has the strong Markov property and continuous path, then from $\lambda(x)<\infty$ we have $\lambda(x)=0$.** It is the exercise 3.1.3 in *Lectures from Markov Processes to Brownian Motion* Chung.

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to solve it, and I think it is rigorous.

Assume $0\leq\lambda(x)<\infty$. Define $T_{0}=\inf\{t>0,X_{t}\neq X_{0}\}$ is the first exit time, and $T_{1}=T_{0}\circ \theta_{T_{0}}+T_{0}$ is the second exit time. Then on $\{X_{T_{0}}=X_{0}, T_{0}<\infty\}$ we have $T_{1}=T_{0}$, i.e., $T_{0}\circ \theta_{T_{0}}=0$. Hence, $$\begin{aligned}0&=\mathbb{P}^{x}(T_{0}\circ \theta_{T_{0}}>0, X_{T_{0}}=x, T_{0}<\infty)\\ &=\mathbb{E}^{x}[\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{\{T_{0}\circ \theta_{T_{0}}>0\}}1_{\{X_{T_{0}}=x\}}1_{\{T_{0}<\infty\}}]\mathcal{F}_{T_{0}}]\\&=\mathbb{E}^{x}[\mathbb{E}^{X_{T_{0}}}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}} 1_{\{X_{0}=x\}}]1_{\{T_{0}<\infty\}}]\\&=\mathbb{E}^{x}[\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}}]1_{\{X_{T_{0}}=x\}}1_{\{T_{0}<\infty\}}]\\&=\mathbb{P}^{x}(X_{T_{0}}=x, T_{0}<\infty), \end{aligned}$$ where the second line uses the tower property, the third line uses strong Markov property as $T_{0}$ is a stopping time relative to some augmented filtration, the forth line use the facts that $$f(y):=\mathbb{E}^{y}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}} 1_{\{X_{0}=x\}}]=\mathbb{E}^{y}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}} 1_{\{y=x\}}]=\mathbb{E}^{y}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}}] 1_{\{y=x\}}=\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}}] 1_{\{y=x\}},$$ and $$\mathbb{E}^{X_{T_{0}}}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}} 1_{\{X_{0}=x\}}]=f(X_{T_{0}})=\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}}] 1_{\{X_{T_{0}}=x\}}.$$ The last line holds as $\mathbb{E}^{x}[1_{\{T_{0}>0\}}]=\exp(-\lambda(x)\cdot0)=1$. Notice that if the path is continuous and $T_{0}<\infty$, then $X_{T_{0}}=X_{0}$. Consequently $\mathbb{P}^{x}(T_{0}<\infty)=0$ and we conclude that $\lambda(x)=0$.